# Is this usage of XML Namespaces correct?

Tags: xml, validation, namespaces, xsd, prefix

I found this very helpful article on WSDL on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996486.aspx, as recommended on SO in another post somewhere.

I was wondering however, if there wasn't a mistake in this example.

Here's the (simplified) schema:

```
<xs:schema 
      targetNamespace="http://example.org/math/types/" 
      xmlns="http://example.org/math/types/" 
    >
    <xs:complexType name="MathInput">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="x" type="xs:double"/>
            <xs:element name="y" type="xs:double"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Add" type="MathInput"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Here's the instance (covered in SOAP):

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <m:Add xmlns:m="http://example.org/math/types/">
            <x>3.14159265358979</x>
            <y>3.14159265358979</y>
        </m:Add>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My uncertainty is about the <x> and <y> elements. Is it o.k. for them to be unqualified?

[Update]
Will the XML instance validate against the given Schema?

Answer (score 2):

It's an unconventional XML design, and I don't like it much, but it's perfectly valid. The schema doesn't specify elementFormDefault="Qualified", therefore the local elements x and y are in no namespace.

Comment: +1 Exactly correct. "unqualified" indicates that elements from the target namespace are not required to be qualified with the namespace prefix.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want.
If I execute the following Xpath against your XML:

```
//*[namespace-uri()='http://example.org/math/types/' and local-name()='x']
```

No elements will be returned.

If I change your XML as follows:-

```
<m:x>3.14159265358979</m:x>
```

The element will be returned.

If you want to leave X and Y unqualified, an Xpath like this will dig them out:-

```
//*[namespace-uri()='http://example.org/math/types/' and local-name()='Add']/x
```

Comment: Nice answer! I like the very practical examples you use to explain what's going on. That way I can refresh my X-Path skills at the same time :-). The example is not my own, and so I was just wondering if they had made a mistake and forgotten to qualify x and y, or if there was some tolerant xml validation mode that didn't mind if you forgot to add the prefixes...

Comment: I guess I could be more specific and ask: Will the XML instance validate against the given Schema?

Comment: Yes with the schema you have specified, the XML will validate against that schema. I checked it using a tool called OxygenXml. If you are working on XSD validation I'd highly recommend you download it.